# I would like to split up the fields in the 'create new content' screen into sections

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

I have a content type with about thirty different fields.  I would like to group them by category and I would also like to split them up so that half of the fields are filled in at the time of creation and the rest are filled in later (as a two-part work flow.)  There is a strong possibility that access to the two field groups will require two different roles.  Is there a good module that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Field Group](https://drupal.org/project/field_group) module to group fields together.

You can use the [Field Permissions](https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module to only allow access to certain fields based on users roles.